# Read Markdown Content In Nuxtjs 3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, markdown, vue-composition-api

I am using Nuxtjs 3, typescript and composition api to develope my new project. I can successfully render content of the markdowns in the project, but in some cases I need to access some specific content of the markdown files.
here is the sample of my markdown :

```
---
header.id: introducing
header.title: my title
header.next: nextFileName
header.prev: previousFileName
---

### service One
 some content here 
<br>
### service two
some content
```

Now, I need to read service one service and service two as array and next , previous and other content of the file.

Does anyone have an idea how I can access these contents in the code?

Comment: @Drenai I use markdown format to render documents in my project, I have lots of pages which are rendered using this format.

Comment: @Drenai This is an old project and I have to transfer the files as they were to the new project that uses Nuxtjs.Unfortunately I could'nt find a way in Nuxt 3 documents to fetch front matters and headings from md files.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use [Content v2](https://content.nuxtjs.org/blog/announcing-v2/), an amazing module for markdown files in Nuxt